# How to look for a specific value in a DataSnapshot with Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to make a cloud function that will trigger on HTTP request (which is sent on a timer), that will remove all childs with a specific value.

The database node looks like this:

```
activities
    4GI1QXUJG0MeQ8Bq19WOdCQFo9r1 //uid
        activity: "hammer"
        id: some ID
        note: "some note"
        timestamp: some timeintervalsince1970
    7IDUiufhiws8939hdfIUHiuhwdi5
        etc....
```

I want to look through all the activities, and if the activity value is "hammer", I want to remove the child.

This is what I have so far

```
exports.deleteHammerNotifications = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    admin.database().ref('activities').once('value', (snapshot) => {

        console.log(snapshot.val())

    });
});
```

which prints:

```
{ 
    '4GI1QXUJG0MeQ8Bq19WOdCQFo9r1': 
      { activity: 'nn',
        id: '4GI1QXUJG0MeQ8Bq19WOdCQFo9r1',
        note: 'Blank note...',
        timestamp: 1498032472 },
     M6xQU5XWTEVbSqBnR3HBAEhA9hI3: 
      { activity: 'hammer',
      id: 'M6xQU5XWTEVbSqBnR3HBAEhA9hI3',
      note: 'some note here...',
      timestamp: 1497973839 },
}
```

My problem is I don't know how to cycle through the DataSnapshot and look for all the childs that has the activity: "hammer" value.
I have done similar function in my xcode project with arrays, but I don't know how to do it with JavaScript.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you want to do a query by child value for all the records that match what you want (activity="hammer"), then delete them using their id.  Querying for the entire set seems wasteful.  Use the javascript docs of the admin SDK to learn the query equivalents of what you would normally do for iOS.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ahh I see, i'm new to the server-side of things, so I was just trying with the same approach as I did in my app. Thanks a lot!

Btw do you have any good places on where to start reading up on such?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To cycle through the matching child nodes, use `snapshot.forEach()`:

```
exports.deleteHammerNotifications = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    admin.database().ref('activities').once('value', (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        console.log(childSnapshot.val())
      });
    });
});
```

But you're still missing a query here to select the correct nodes. Without such a query you might as well call `admin.database().ref('activities').remove()`.

To most efficiently delete a number of items from the database and write a single response back to the user, use this function (which I modified from something I needed recently):

```
exports.cleanup = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var query = admin.database().ref("activities").orderByChild("activity").equalTo("hammer");
  query.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
    console.log("cleanup: "+snapshot.numChildren()+" activities");
    var updates = {};
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      updates["activities/"+child.key] = null;
    });
    admin.database().ref().update(updates).then(() => {
      res.status(200).send(snapshot.numChildren()+" activities deleted");
    }).catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    })
  });
});
```

Learn more:

- [Firebase documentation on querying](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#ordering-by-a-specified-child-key)
- [Firebase blog post on multi-location updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer!

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if its possible, but IF you can start a "child_added" listener, once the HTTPS trigger has run, you can do like this.

```
ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
 if (snapshot.child("activity").val() === 'hammer') {
 var value = snapshot.child("activity").val();
})
```

I am doing the exact same thing to see if people are still subscribed to my mailing list or not, and IF they are, they will receive a mail.

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: This isn't a good idea, because child_added listeners don't ever stop listening - you won't be told when all the data available at any given moment has been sent.  It's important to use only a single query that finishes in a predictable fashion.