# Delete specific value from firebase database using swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Database

[image]

I tried using this bit of code but it doesn't seem to work. I take the name the user selects and store it in nameList.

Lets say I store Blake Wodruff in nameList[0].
How do I remove only that name?

```
var nameList = [String](repeating: "", count:100)

func remove() {

        print(nameList[countAddNames])
        
        let usernameRef =  Database.database().reference().child("Candidate 1").child("alton").child(nameList[countAddNames]);
        usernameRef.removeValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to or delete a node, you must specify its entire path. So to delete node `0` from your JSON, you'd do:

```
let usernameRef =  Database.database().reference().child("Candidate 1").child("alton").child("0");
usernameRef.removeValue();
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
let usernameRef =  Database.database().reference().child("Candidate 1/alton/0");
usernameRef.removeValue();
```

---

If you only know the name of the user you want to remove, you'll need to first look up its index/full path before you can remove it. If you have the data in your application already, you can do it in that code. Otherwise you may have to [use a database query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) (specifically `.queryOrderedByValue` and `.queryEqualToValue`) to determine where the value exists in the database.

Also see: [Delete a specific child node in Firebase swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52688644/delete-a-specific-child-node-in-firebase-swift)

---

Once you remove a value from your JSON structure, Firebase may no longer recognize it as an array. For this reason it is highly recommended to **not** use arrays for the structure that you have. In fact, I'd model your data as a set, which in JSON would look like:

```
"alton": {
  "Jake Jugg": true,
  "Blake Wodruff": true,
  "Alissa Sanchez": true
}
```

This would automatically:

1. Prevent duplicates, as each name can by definition only appear once.
2. Make removing a candidate by their name as easy as `Database.database().reference().child("Candidate 1/alton/Jake Jugg").removeValue()`

For more on this, also see my answer to [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)